# How to create a node_modules folder for a different architecture/platform?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

As the title says, I'd like to create a node_modules folder as if it were run on a different OS / Architecture.

Example: I'm on an M1 mac, I'd like to create 3 versions of my node_modules folder:

- darwin/arm64 (my machine, I can just run `npm install` as normal)
- darwin/x86
- linux/x86

I also want to be able to create the above from an Intel Mac.

I've looked around and seen some references to node-pre-gyp but I think that just recompiles dependencies that use node-pre-gyp to manage cross-arch. Some dependencies don't and some dependencies may only get pulled in on some platforms (e.g. fsevents).

I've seen reference to maybe using Docker to do this, but I'm a little but unsure how I could set this up - it also seems like it could be quite painful. If that's the only way though, so be it...